# Have page come up without the .aspx

Tags: asp.net, url

I am using ASP.NET Web Forms.

I have a situation where an ASPX page needs to come up without the `.aspx` extension.

Following is an example (not real site):

```
  www.abc.com/firstpage
```

The page is actually called `firstpage.aspx`, but I wonder if I could make it work without the `.aspx`.

The reason why this is important is because an email got sent out 
with `www.abc.com/firstpage`, and now I need to figure out how to 
make it programatically go to `www.abc.com/firstpage.aspx`.

Comment: May want to look into [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) or [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx). Both are supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using .net 4.5 you can use Asp.net Friendly URLS:
http://aspnetfriendlyurls.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty: create firstpage folder, create index.html file in it. Place this inside:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/firstpage.aspx">
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

This will fix your problem without messing around with URL rewrites, etc.

Comment: A perfect quick fix but he may need to ensure that `index.html` is one of the default documents in IIS (in case they have been changed from the standard)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0 or later, then you can use ASP.NET routing in WebForms.

Read [Walkthrough: Using ASP.NET Routing in a Web Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use a URL rewrite rule (i.e. to rewrite `www.abc.com/firstpage` to `www.abc.com/firstpage.aspx`).  IIS and third-party rewrite modules (e.g. ones compatible with Apache syntax) can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "extensionless URLS" and "URL Rewriting".

There is a good article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx).